# Conditional Multiplication in Loop

Tags: powershell, csv

I've got a script that goes through a CSV file with two formats of data (`XY:ZABC` or `0.xyz`). The values are then saved in a CSV file with one column and variable number of rows. I am trying to setup my script such that, for numbers of value `0.xyz`, it will multiply by 1440 and then store it in `$Values`. The numbers of format `XY:ZABC` will be stored as they are in `$Values` as well.

```psh
$Values = @(Get-Content *\source.csv -Raw) -split '\s+' |
          Where-Object {$_ -like '*:*' -or '0.*'}
"UniqueActiveFaults" | Out-File *\IdealOutput.csv
$Values | Sort-Object -Unique | Out-File *\IdealOutput.csv
```

I've tried to do this by adding the following code:

```psh
foreach ($i in $Values) {
    if ($i -lt 1) {$i*1440} 
}
```

I've also tried to do it with a `do {$i*1440} while ($I -lt 1)` loop, but the result is the number `0.xyz` shown 1440 times. I believe it's due to the type of data that `$Values` is taking, but not sure.

Sample data:

```
0.12345
00:9090 90:4582
0.12346
0.1145
0.145654
0.5648
01:9045 90:4500
90:4546
BA: 1117 BA:2525
```

Comment: can you add some sample of your csv data please

Comment: @Paul, I've added sample data to original post

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `$Values` is an array of strings.  The "multiply" operation on a string is to repeat it.  To treat it like a number, cast to float before multiplying.

```
foreach ($i in $Values) {
    if ($i -lt 1) {[float]$i * 1440} 
}
```

As Tony Hinkle pointed out, this loop will simply output the result of the operation to the caller (or the console if you don't pipe it).  If you want to your array to reflect the change, you have to store it back.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Values.length; $i++) {
    if ($Values[$i] -lt 1) { [float]$Values[$i] *= 1440 }
}
```

Be aware this will leave some of your values array as strings and some as floats.  Depending on what you do with it, you might have to do further casts.

Comment: thank you. This works great. I do have two questions: (a) Could you please explain your second piece of code, I am not sure I understand the use of $Values.length and the if conditional action in the second line. (b) Also, the output of my loop is giving me a valid number but also returning an additional 0 (zero) every time. Any idea where this zero is coming from?

Comment: The `for` in the second bit is an alternate loop iteration syntax where `$i` is the numeric index into the array, and goes from 0 to the array's length.  It is necessary because `foreach` doesn't give access to the original array to modify it.  As for the extra 0, you would have to paste your code, possibly in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$i*1440` that is simply telling Powershell to multiply the two values and return the product.  If you want to change the value of $i, you need to use `$i = $1 * 1440`.

You may have other issues as well, but this is assuming that you are getting the correct values assigned to $i from the input.